CTRL+L go to root directory
Hi guys I'm having an issue with the command CTRL+L, no matter where I am, the command go to root folder, check it out:

I have no idea what appends and I really don't know how to fix it. I have Elementary OS 7.1 Horus Built on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Linux 6.8.0-49-generic)
Update
I can confirm that the issue happens io.elementary.terminal only, I just installed terminator and the shortcut works OK

Same here, Elementary OS 7.1, terminal with CTRL-L killing bash (new pid) and going to / . No solution at the moment.

Same here, after the update days ago, the Ctrl-k killing bash and going to home directory too.
This isn't what the bash manual says.
#man bash
clear-screen (C-l)
              Clear the screen, then redraw the current line, leaving the current line at the top of the screen.  With an argument, refresh the  current  line  without
              clearing the screen.

Killing and Yanking
       kill-line (C-k)
              Kill the text from point to the end of the line.

